# How can I access the case of a switch with two conditions in java?

Tags: java, switch-statement, uppercase, lowercase

I'm making a program with a menu where the user is asked to select an option labeled by letters:

> a) option 1
>
> b) option 2
>
> c) option 3
>
> ...
>
> Select an option:

The program needs to be case insensitive so lowercase and uppercase are both accepted. I want to make a switch to organize the different options but as it is case insensitive, do I need to convert the option to lowercase or uppercase or is there an option to enter the case independently of it's lower or upper?

Comment: `switch (input.toLowercase()) {...`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use multiple `case` expressions for the upper and lower cases:

```java
switch (input) {
    case "a":
    case "A":
        doA();
    case "b":
    case "B":
        doB();
    case "c":
    case "C":
        doC();
}
```

But as you can see, this gets really clunky really fast. Converting everything to lowercase (or uppercase, if you prefer) seems a lot simpler:

```java
switch (input.toLowerCase()) {
    case "a":
        doA();
    case "b":
        doB();
    case "c":
        doC();
}
```